# Runtime error 3001 'Arguments are of the wrong type or out of acceptable range...'

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have an Excel table and want to update SQL Server table records' date value (with getdate function) which referred by 12th column of Excel.

My code is as below, but I'm seeing:

> Run-time error 3001 Arguments are of the wrong type or out of acceptable range or are in conflict with one another.

In SQL table MODIFIEDDATE field is datetime type, and MAINREF field is integer type.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim conn2 As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst2 As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim j As Integer

conn2.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=abc;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=logodb;Data Source=A3650;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto"
conn2.Open

For j = 0 To 1900
    If Sayfa1.Cells(j + 4, 12) = "" Then
        Sayfa1.Cells(j + 4, 13) = "empty"
    Else
        rst2.Open "UPDATE T_015 SET MODIFIEDDATE=GETDATE() WHERE MAINREF='" & Sayfa1.Cells(j + 4, 12) & "'", conn, 1, 3
        rst2.Close
    End If
Next j

End Sub
```

I've tried to change the SQL query like, (CInt(cell.value))

```
rst2.Open "UPDATE T_015 SET MODIFIEDDATE=GETDATE() WHERE MAINREF='" & CInt(Sayfa1.Cells(j + 4, 12)) & "'", conn, 1, 3
```

but, it didn't work.

Comment: If `MAINREF` is numeric, why compare it to a string representing a number? Shouldn't that be `...  WHERE MAINREF=" & Sayfa1.Cells(j + 4, 12)` ?

Comment: you'r right, i'd changed like tihs ...WHERE MAINPRODREF=" & Sayfa1.Cells(j + 4, 12) & "", conn2, 1, 3 but this time i'm seeing **"wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"** message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ADODB.Recordset object should not be used for an UPDATE query. Execute the SQL statement directly from the ADODB.Connection

```
Dim conn2 As New ADODB.Connection

conn2.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=MYSERVER;Database=TMP;UID=sa;password=abc;"
conn2.Open

conn2.Execute "UPDATE T_015 SET MODIFIEDDATE=GETDATE() WHERE MAINREF=1"
```

Comment: when i changed like you offer, it cause **"wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"** message

Comment: my apologies, I'd left the `..., conn, 1, 3` off the right end. It should have been removed. (btw, that was `conn` not `conn2` in your question's code)

Comment: i realised that, before asking the question, I edited it but error message is the same.

Comment: conn2.Execute "UPDATE T_015 SET MODIFIEDDATE=GETDATE() WHERE MAINREF=" & Sayfa1.Cells(j + 4, 12) & "", conn2, 1, 3  > just changed this line. And error message indicates the first line of the code with yellow "Private Sub ..."

Comment: I changed the connection string to one I was more familiar with and ran a 'dumbed-down' version. The **T_015** table I constructed in the **TMP** database on the **MYSERVER** machine ran through this quickly without a problem.

Comment: Except for the name of the server and the sa password, that was the code. I have a TMP database on my server and I quickly made up a new table called T_015 with MODIFIEDDATE (datetime) and MAINREF (int) fields.

Comment: Even i wanted to update another field, i'm seeing the same (and also colours the first line (private sub commandbutton1... line). I edited like this: conn2.Execute "UPDATE T_015 SET ACTIVE=1 WHERE MAINREF=3737", conn2, 1, 3

Comment: You're using early binding. Did you add Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 to Tools ► References? Remove the `, conn2, 1, 3` from the right end of the SQL statement.

Comment: i'm really appreciate for your help and your patience. It is solved  after i remove the 2.8 library and add Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 library. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can fulfil your requirements and it seems that you are mixing the two.

One way is to update records one at a time, and to do this you would use the `Connection` object or, more preferably, the `Command` object. I say preferably because parameterised commands are a far more robust way of executing your SQL. If you intend to use SQL then it's something you probably ought to read about. The way you would do that is as follows:

```
Public Sub ParameterisedProcedure()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim j As Integer

    'Read the sheet data
    v = Sayfa1.Range("L4", "M1904").Value2

    'Open the database connection
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
                              "Password=abc;" & _
                              "Persist Security Info=True;" & _
                              "User ID=sa;" & _
                              "Initial Catalog=logodb;" & _
                              "Data Source=A3650;" & _
                              "Use Procedure for Prepare=1;" & _
                              "Auto"
    conn.Open

    'Loop through the values to update records
    For j = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        If IsEmpty(v(j, 1)) Then
            v(j, 2) = "empty"
        Else
            'Create the parameterised command
            Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
            cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
            cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE T_015 " & _
                              "SET MODIFIEDDATE=? " & _
                              "WHERE MAINREF=?"
            prm = cmd.CreateParameter(Type:=adDate, Value:=Now)
            cmd.Parameters.Append prm
            prm = cmd.CreateParameter(Type:=adInteger, Value:=v(j, 1))
            cmd.Parameters.Append prm
            cmd.Execute
        End If
    Next

    'Write the updated values
    Sayfa1.Range("L4", "M1904").Value = v

    'Close the database
    Set prm = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    conn.Close

End Sub
```

The other way is to use `Transactions` and you would indeed use a `Recordset` for that (ie similar to what you have already done). In this case I'd suggest it is the better way to do it because executing one command at a time (as in the above code) is very slow. A vastly quicker way would be to commit all your updates in one transaction. Like a parameterised command, it's also safe from rogue strings entering your SQL command text. The code would look like this:

```
Public Sub TransactionProcedure()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cmdText As String
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim j As Integer

    'Read the sheet data
    v = Sayfa1.Range("L4", "M1904").Value2

    'Open the database connection
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
                              "Password=abc;" & _
                              "Persist Security Info=True;" & _
                              "User ID=sa;" & _
                              "Initial Catalog=logodb;" & _
                              "Data Source=A3650;" & _
                              "Use Procedure for Prepare=1;" & _
                              "Auto"
    conn.Open

    'Retrieve the data
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    cmdText = "SELECT * FROM  T_015"
    rs.Open cmdText, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

    'Loop through the values to update the recordset
    On Error GoTo EH
    conn.BeginTrans
    For j = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        If IsEmpty(v(j, 1)) Then
            v(j, 2) = "empty"
        Else
            'Find and update the record
            rs.Find "MAINREF=" & CStr(v(j, 1))
            If Not rs.EOF Then
                rs!ModifiedDate = Now
                rs.Update
            End If
        End If
    Next
    conn.CommitTrans

    'Write the updated values
    Sayfa1.Range("L4", "M1904").Value = v

    'Close the database
    rs.Close
    conn.Close
    Exit Sub

EH:
    conn.RollbackTrans
    Sayfa1.Range("L4", "M1904").Value = v
    rs.Close
    conn.Close
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```