# Check if ADODB Recordset contains multiple criteria ? Vba

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to check if my recordset contains multiple criteria. I tried with the `.Find` with a filter :

```
filter2 = "[Nom] = '" & oLookFullName & "'" And "[nomEntreprise] = '" & objContact.CompanyName & "'"
rs.MoveFirst
rs.Find filter2, 1, adSearchForward
```

but after few researches, it authorizes just one criteria. My question is there **an alternative** to do it and how ?

```
                                        EDIT
```

**Find Method (ADO)**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/find-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver15

> Only a single-column name may be specified in criteria. This method
> does not support multi-column searches.

Comment: How about using the `filter` property of the ado recordset?

Comment: The `And` needs to be inside double-quotes.  For example filter2 = "[Nom] = '" & oLookFullName & "' And [nomEntreprise] = '" & objContact.CompanyName & "'"

Comment: Run-time error 3001 Arguments are of the wrong type or out of acceptable range or are in conflict with one another

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the search criteria a bit:

```
filter2 = "[Nom] = '" & oLookFullName & "' And [nomEntreprise] = '" & objContact.CompanyName & "'"
rs.MoveFirst
rs.Find filter2, 1, adSearchForward
```

Comment: Run-time error 3001 Arguments are of the wrong type or out of acceptable range or are in conflict with one another

on line `rs.Find filter2, 1, adSearchForwars`

Comment: See [Runtime error 3001 'Arguments are of the wrong type or out of acceptable range…'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33753250/runtime-error-3001-arguments-are-of-the-wrong-type-or-out-of-acceptable-range)

Comment: thanks for your help. I just write an edit about .find method. Do you have an alternative of this method with multiple criteria ?

Comment: @ThonyNadhir As mentioned by Unhandled Exception, you could try the `Filter` property.  It supports multiple criteria.